# Excel Vlookup Column in another Sheet

Tags: excel, vlookup

So i have been playing with Excel for a while, and one thing led to another, i wanted to try this: How do i make the "Employee ID" cells in this Sheet here:

[image]

To refer to the "Employee ID" cells in this other Sheet?

[image]

Such that each employee in the first sheet have only their Employee ID rightfully and properly attached.

I have tried VLOOKUP but i keep getting N/A Errors despite my best efforts. Here is the Formula i tried in Excel:

[image]

The results returned was this:

[image]

Is there a solution to my predicament?

Answer (score 2):

You need index() with match() as vlookup cannot work to the left of its indexing column.

So try:

```
=index(Sheet2!A:A,match(B2,sheet2!B:B,0))
```

Typed without testing as you gave images not data.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use XLookup, a relatively new formula. E.g.,
=XLOOKUP(A2;Sheet2!A:A;Sheet2!B:B)