# How to find the right xlookup formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am stuck on the right excel formula to use for my situation....

I have a spreadsheet A with that information:

| IP |
| --- |
| 127.0.0.1 |
| 128.11.21.2 |

I have another spreadsheet B with that information:

| IP | IP2 | IP3 | OS | Techno | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 127.0.0.1 | 127.0.0.1 | 212.22.23.25 | Windows | Oracle | None |
| 128.11.21.2 | 215.11.51.89 | 215.11.51.98 | Linux | Java | Fix it |

I would like to check if the information on the spreadsheet A (IP) are  in the spreadsheet B (IP, IP2, IP3)
if it is the case, I want to add the column OS, Techno and Comment liked to the same IP.

I used Xlookup but it didn't work...

Someone could guide me ?

Thanks,

ST

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel Vlookup Column in another Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69879810/excel-vlookup-column-in-another-sheet)

Comment: I tried xlookup from the link and match/index, did not work for my case :/

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with [ms-word]. If it doesn't, can you edit your post to remove the [ms-word] tag?

Answer (score 1):

So, yet another (boring) example of the use of vlookup() and index() with match():

[image]

So an update to use the column headings, removed the if(0 with vlookup() but you can put that back:

[image]