# Automatically fill in a table with selected columns of another table based on matching rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, row, lookup

**Sheet1** (Dynamically growing large table — Table1):

| Id | Description | Dependency Id | % of completion | Owmer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Task 1 | 3 | 50% | Carlos |
| 2 | Task 2 |  | 70% | Thomas |
| 3 | Task 3 |  |  | Jessica |
| 4 | Task 4 | 1 | 20% | Eddy |

When there are thousands of rows present in Sheet1, it's not easy to find dependencies (too much scrolling up/down).
I'm trying to create another table (Table2) on Sheet2 that gives an overview of dependent items in Sheet1 with their corresponding dependencies, side by side with selected columns.

After filtering out dependent items from Table1, how can I look up the corresponding rows based on Id (Id with Dependency Id) matching & select relevant columns dynamically without copying & pasting formulas (Table2 grows/reduces as rows on Table1 are added/removed)?

I tried filtering dependent items from Table1 with this formula in Table2 using table name:`=FILTER(INDEX(Table1,SEQUENCE(ROWS(Table1)),{1,2,3,4}),Table1[Dependency Id]<>"")`

**Sheet2** (Overview of dependencies based on **Dependency Id** — Table2)

| Id | Description | % of completion | Dependency Id | Description | % of completion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Task 1 | 50% | 3 |  |  |
| 4 | Task 4 | 20% | 1 |  |  |

How can I manage to read the Description & % of completion columns from Table1 based on the Dependency Id from the filtered table above without manual intervention with an Excel formula? Any help, please?

Expected Result:

| Id | Description | % of completion | Dependency Id | Description | % of completion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Task 1 | 50% | 3 | Task 3 |  |
| 4 | Task 4 | 20% | 1 | Task 1 | 50 % |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the right xlookup formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75557372/how-to-find-the-right-xlookup-formula)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Structured Reference for Table1, `XLOOKUP`, `COUNTA`, & `OFFSET`
For the "Description" column:
`=XLOOKUP(table2_dependecy_id, table1[id], table1[Description], "Not found", 0)`

For the "% of completion" column:
`=XLOOKUP(table2_dependecy_id, table1[id], table1[% of completion], "Not found", 0)`

In both formulas:

- `table2_dependency_id`: `=OFFSET(Overview!$D$13,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet2!$J$13:$J$1048576))`
  for my case, it starts at row 13, dynamically growing; COUNTA gives us the only the non-empty cells count.
- the 0 indicates exact match when `XLOOKUP`

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you could make use of row AND column in index() like so:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Solar Mike. This solution still needs manual intervention to auto-fill as Table B in your example continuously grows with the number of rows (would be nice if the formula can handle all the cells in a column) + adapting the formula for each column that needs to be copied in Table A looks like a necessity.

Comment: @Skoby so given the technique an opportunity for you to improve your skills...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try Excel's PowerQuery

1. PowerQuery the source table Table1
2. Reference this query as Table_Output
3. Filter Table_Output for tasks with dependencies.
4. Merge the Table_Output with Table1 by matching Dependency Id with Id.
5. The Table_Output is linked to Table1, and can be Refreshed for updates.