# Copy cells based on matching index numbers on excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Table to copy cells from**

[image: Table to copy cells from]

**Table to paste cells to**

[image: Table to paste cells on]

The idea is to take the 2 cells in front of the one with index 3 in the first table and paste them in the second table where the indexes match. Since I have over 100 indexes and this process will likely be repeated in the future, how can I make this automatically?

Comment: Which 2 cells in front of which index 3? *"In front of"* means before or to the left. Use cell addresses to explain what needs to be done. Use a few examples, not just one.

Comment: So many examples of the use of index() with and without match() on here, just have a look. But here is one that uses index with match for both row and column. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75560353/4961700

Comment: Why not just add a lookup (XLOOKUP, VLOOKUP, INDEX/Match) to your destination table and then use Copy/Paste Special as Values?

Comment: You could also write the values to an array and write the array to the destination table.

Answer (score 0):

Type this formula in cell G4.

```
=INDEX(B$1:B$13,MATCH($F4,$A$1:$A$13,0),1)
```

where change the value 13 (both) to the last row value of the source table .

Then copy and paste cell G4 in the G and H column to the end of the target table.

[image]